# Can't add any stackexchange sites to careers profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I try to fill my profile, I can't add my Stack Exchange accounts! Why is this? Is this a bug?

[image: Where are the Stack Exchange sites]

Browser: Google Chrome 9.0.597.67 beta, Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: Maybe related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80489/email-already-registered-error-when-updating-careers-2-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again now.  There are some users with old / bad network association information.  When you go to the profile edit page, we now try to update your association info.

Comment: Yes, it works now!