# Email already registered error when updating Careers 2 profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

When I wanted to add my website to my Careers 2 profile I got the following error:
[image: Email error]

I did not change the field email-address. I have removed my email from the image, but I assume the devvers can see it ( my profile: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/petersmit )

Answer (score 5):

This happens if you already have a profile on careers... Looks like I found an old one for you - I'll email you directly so we can take care of this.

**Edit** The above not withstanding it seems that for a few accounts the transition to 2.0 didn't quite go as intended, leading to the same behavior. Email us at careers [at] stackoveflow [dot] com if you run into this.